# Backbone.js: this.collection.models returns empty array

Tags: backbone.js

I'm using Backbone.js to display a list of items (stations) from an API request.

My question has been asked a lot it seems, I have gone through as many as possible of the other questions' solutions, but I still have a problem.

Here is code below:

```
(function($) {

    _.templateSettings = {
    interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
    };
//  models
    var Station = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: '../api/admin/stations/',
        idAttribute: "_id",
        defaults: {
            _id: null,
            country: 'ZA'
        }
    });

//  collections
    var StationList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Station,
        url: '../api/admin/stations/'
});

//  views
/*
 * Station View
 */
    var StationView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'article',
        className:  'station-container',
        template: $("#stationListTemplate").html(),

        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });

/*
 * Master View (Station List)
 */
    var StationListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#stationListView"),

        initialize: function() {
            this.collection = new StationList();
            this.collection.fetch({
                success: this.render()
            });
        },
        render: function() {
            var that = this;
            console.log(this.collection.models); // RETURNS EMPTY ARRAY
            _.each(this.collection.models, function (item) {
// NOTHING HAPPENS AS THE ARRAY IS EMPTY
                that.renderStation(item);
            }, this);
        },
        renderStation: function (item) {
            var stationView = new StationView({
                model: item
            });
            console.log(stationView);
            this.$el.append(stationView.render().el);
        }
    });

//  load views
    var _stationList = new StationListView;
} (jQuery));
```

I have added comments above in CAPS for where I get an error. When I `console.log(that)` or `console.log(this.collection)` I can see the collection, but I can't access its models immediately after that.

I just don't know what I am doing wrong that's making me unable to access the model. Any help would be highly apreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i quote your code :

```
success: this.render()
```

i'm pretty sure you should either write

```
success:this.render
```

or

```
success:function(){
 this.render()
}
```

because by the time you define success callback (and execute it according to your code ), the collection hasn't been fetched yet. There may be other errors though , but this one is pretty obvious

Comment: No ways! I initially tried success: this.render but I got an error. That was a few hours back. Tried it now, and I can get the models, but I have an error with this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));. I know what's causing that, and I just fixed it. Now 'it just works'. Thanks, it's past midnight in my part of the world, and I've been stuck on my PC for about 6 hours trying to figure it out. 
I was about to give up and resort to jQuery :)

Comment: When you are stuck with a problem always get a break, do something else and come back later with a fresh look on the issue ,especially when you've been stuck for 6 hours. Glad i could help.

Comment: That wasn't gonna help. I'm new at Backbonejs, I've used so many frameworks and SDKs I thought it woudln't be that hard to figure it out. In theory I get the logic, but translating it is still difficult. Also doesn't help that most of the tutorials out there are a bit inadequate. Thanks